# Limit registers per thread Alea GPU (--maxregcount)

Tags: nvidia, aleagpu

Nvidia Visual Profiler recommends that I try compile with the maxregcount flag. Is there anything equivalent in Alea GPU and how is it used?

I am using JIT-compilation, and have found the JITMaxRegisters option, but it seems to have no effect on the register count per thread.

```
{ worker.DefaultCompileOptions.ToProfilingConfig () 
   with JITMaxRegisters = Some 60; 
        MinimalArch = DeviceArch.Create("sm35")}
```

With this compile option the visual profiler still says 72 registers/thread are being used.

Are there any equivalent to maxregcount or __launch_bounds__ that I am missing?